# Getting 404 on HasMany from 1 Resource, but not another Resource to the same record

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I have an existing Laravel/Nova project and tables.  I am introducing a new set of tables into the mix.

Old Structure:
Field -> FieldValue

New Structure:
ComplexField -> ComplexFieldValue
Field -> FieldValue -> ComplexFieldValue

If I try to use the edit icon from the FieldValue with (HasMany), I get a blank screen and a notice of a 404 error in my network window.

If I view the record then edit it.  It works fine.

If I edit from the ComplexField, it will successfully bring up the screen to edit the record.

**The browser headers show for the working method:**

Request URL: http://localhost/nova-api/complex-fields/field/complexFieldValues
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
...
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.19
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Host: localhost
Referer: http://localhost/nova/resources/complex-field-values/42/edit?viaResource=complex-fields&viaResourceId=3&viaRelationship=complexFieldValues

**Where as the non working method shows:**

Request URL: http://localhost/nova-api/field-values/field/complexFieldValues
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
...
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.19
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Host: localhost
Referer: http://localhost/nova/resources/complex-field-values/42/edit?viaResource=field-values&viaResourceId=291&viaRelationship=complexFieldValues

Any ideas on what would be causing this behavior?

I thought maybe the field-values may be causing routing issues.  I changed them over to simple-field-values without success.

Both Resources are using:

```
HasMany::make('Complex Field Values', 'complexFieldValues'),
```

Both Models are using a trait that uses the models foreign key.

```
    public function complexFieldValues()
    {
        return $this->HasMany('App\Models\ComplexFieldValue', $this->foreignKey, 'id', \App\Nova\ComplexFieldValue::class);
    }
```

Comment: any joy with this?